# Write quickly GMP variables in files

Tags: c, performance, file, gmp

I would like to know how to write a `mpz_t` number of the GMP library in a file quickly. For example, I have the following C code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gmp.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    mpz_t p, q, inter1, inter2, tmp;
    int i;
    double t;
    FILE* fichier;

    mpz_inits(p, q, inter1, inter2, tmp, NULL);
    mpz_set_ui(p, 1);
    mpz_set_ui(q, 1);

    t = (double) clock();

    for (i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        mpz_set(tmp, p);
        mpz_mul(inter1, q, q);
        mpz_mul_ui(inter1, inter1, 2);
        mpz_mul(inter2, p, p);
        mpz_add(p, inter1, inter2);

        mpz_mul(q, tmp, q);
        mpz_mul_ui(q, q, 2);
    }

    printf("%lf\n", ((double) clock() - t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    t = (double) clock();

    fichier = fopen("num.txt", "w");
    mpz_out_str(fichier, 10, p);
    fclose(fichier);

    printf("%lf\n", ((double) clock() - t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    mpz_clears(p, q, inter1, inter2, tmp, NULL);
}
```

And it takes only 6 secondes to compute the value of the variable `p` whereas to write the value of this variable in a file, it takes 22 secondes.

How can I improve the writing time in the file ?

Comment: Writing to the file means converting to number to decimal, which is a very lengthy operation. If you wrote the number as hexadecimal you'd get faster times. `mpz_out_str(fichier, 16, p);`

Comment: The number is converted to decimal ? And if it is written as hexadecimal, it will not ?

Comment: Ok. I understand how GMP works.

Comment: Internally GMP uses a binary format, so conversion to decimal is required to output a number in decimal notation. Conversion to hexdecimal is also required to output the number in hexadecimal notation but this is a much faster operation because hexadecimal is much closer to the internal binary format that GMP uses.